# Spotify Web Playback SDK - Play Full Song

Tags: spotify

I am trying to use the Spotify Web Playback SDK to play full songs in a browser.  Following [the docs](https://beta.developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/) I am still confused of how to actually play a song using this API.  I can control playback/volume etc of a song thats already being played using my account, but there are no endpoints in the API to give it a track payload and have it play back that song.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the Spotify Connect Web API (docs here: https://beta.developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/player/)

Using the device_id you get from the Web Playback SDK, simply make a call to `/me/player/play`. Here's how that would look with AJAX:

```
  $.ajax({
   url: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play?device_id=" + device_id,
   type: "PUT",
   data: '{"uris": ["spotify:track:5ya2gsaIhTkAuWYEMB0nw5"]}',
   beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + _token );},
   success: function(data) { 
     console.log(data)
   }
  });
```

Check out this simple Glitch example to get started: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/spotify-web-playback